# Changed meanings in borrowed terms

Tags: semantics

Looking for examples of changed meanings for words borrowed from non-English languages. Example is mis-use of entrée.
Original French  entrée  =  entry, entrance, appetizer, etc.

Entrée is commonly misused to mean the main course of a meal.

Comment: Why do you think that's a misuse in English? English is not French, and English words borrowed from French are no longer French words. Language changes.

Comment: If you're interested in the semantic shift in the word "entrée" specifically, check out "The Language of Food: A Linguist Reads the Menu" by Dan Jurafsky.

Comment: Interesting book, jogloran. Thanks for the tip.  I am still looking for similar words or phrases that have different meanings from original language. I've seen examples mentioned in other languages (e.g., Japanese).

Comment: Staying within food, consider also ‘dinner’ (now usually = evening meal), from Old French _disner_ ‘lunch’, itself based on Latin _dis-jejun-_ ‘breakfast’; and also Danish _frokost_ ‘lunch’ vs Swedish and Norwegian _frukost/frokost_ ‘breakfast’. Also, an entrée **is** an appetiser in English outside North America – the meaning ‘main course’ is pretty much only found in the US and Canada and is quite parallel to the other moving meals mentioned above.